# Remove Gnome from Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: gnome, uninstall, 16.10

I installed the Gnome desktop environment in order to test it out, but now i'd like to revert my system back to the way it was before installing it (Ubuntu 16.10).

How do I remove the Gnome DE, it's specific apps and its extensions?

EDIT:

I originally installed Ubuntu 16.10 on my machine, and subsequently installed the gnome desktop environment via apt.

Comment: How do you install gnome ? The removing is depend to how you install it

Comment: What command you use to install gnome ?